# Which metro does NetBeans-Glassfish uses?

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, java-metro-framework

I am new to NetBeans world and I installed NetBeans 7.1.2 which comes bundled with Glassfish-3.1.2

I am developing a metro application and wanted to debug it, so went to library manager to add source files. But noticed that the 'Library manager' shows METRO 2.0 in its libraries.
[image]

So, I wanted to upgrade the metro to latest 2.2 and started GlassFish update Tool. In the installed Components lists, it shows metro 2.2-13 is installed!
[image]

So please help me understand, among these two which version of metro is used by glassfish when I run/debug through NetBeans? If 2.2 is in use, how do I add source file to it to debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enable metro tube logs and found that Metro 2.2 is in use.